# Trying to read in arrays from multiple .txt files in Python but nothing is appearing

Tags: python, arrays, loops, output

I'm attempting to read in multiple .txt files into my program, but when I run the program, the precip variable does not print and there are no errors.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
year = 2014
while year > 2019:  
    day = 1
    while day < 31:
        infile = 'p24i_{0:4.0f}06{1:02.0f}_sortbyvalue.txt'.format(year, day)
        data_in = pd.read_csv(infile, skiprows=6, delim_whitespace=True, header=None).values
        precip = data_in[:,0]
        print(precip)
        day+=1  
    year+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`year` is `2014`, so the code inside your `while year > 2019:` loop will not run, since `2014 > 2019` is `False`, perhaps you meant:

```
while year < 2019:
    # do
```